# What were pre-internet stock books called?

Tags: economy

I listened to a podcast recently where someone described looking up quarterly business and stock reports in a big book at the library in the days before the Internet. What were these books called? I'd like to collect some.

Comment: Are you asking about company/corporation accounts (i.e. company performance) or about stock trading history (i.e. stock performance)?

Comment: @Steve both, really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These books were called "Moody's Manuals" and are still published today under the Mergent brand.

Source: [The Motley Fool](http://www.fool.com/investing/value/2007/08/29/the-intelligent-investors-tool-set.aspx)